# Need help configuring react-hot-loader

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hot-loader, hot-module-replacement

I'm using the latest ASP.NET 2.0 react SPA template, which is created with the command **dotnet new react.** It works great out of the box, with hot module replacement (code edits update in browser automatically).

Then I wanted to add a top level app container, called **App** to hold application state, as described in this blog post:
[react without redux article](https://medium.com/@blairanderson/you-probably-dont-need-redux-1b404204a07f).  Should be simple, right?  Note that the article uses javascript, but I'm using Typescript, since that's how the template was designed.  But after adding a simple top level container component and updating the hot loader config, it doesn't work.  I get an error that the component doesn't know how to reload itself.  This is the code that is working (from the template):

```
import './styles/site.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as RoutesModule from './routes';
let routes = RoutesModule.routes;

function renderApp() {
    // This code starts up the React app when it runs in a browser. It sets up the routing
    // configuration and injects the app into a DOM element.
    const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href')!;
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <BrowserRouter children={ routes } basename={ baseUrl } />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('react-app')
    );
}

renderApp();

// Allow Hot Module Replacement
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./routes', () => {
        routes = require<typeof RoutesModule>('./routes').routes;
        renderApp();
    });
}
```

And this is the code after my changes, that is NOT working:

```
import './styles/site.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as RoutesModule from './routes';
import  App  from './components/App';
import * as AppModule from './components/App'

let routes = RoutesModule.routes;

const render = (Component: any) => {
    // This code starts up the React app when it runs in a browser. It sets up the routing
    // configuration and injects the app into a DOM element.
    //const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href')!;
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Component />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('react-app')
    );
}

render(App);

// Allow Hot Module Replacement
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
        const nextRoot = (require('./components/App') as typeof AppModule).default;
        render(nextRoot);
    });
}
```

For reference, here's the ./routes file (I did not change this file):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';

export const routes = <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
    <Route path='/counter' component={ Counter } />
    <Route path='/fetchdata' component={ FetchData } />
</Layout>;
```

And here's my new App container component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as RoutesModule from '../routes';
import { ReactElement } from "react";
let routes = RoutesModule.routes;

interface AppState {
    stateDescription: string;
}

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { stateDescription: 'My Cool App State' };
    }

    public render() {
        const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href')!;
        return (
            <BrowserRouter children = { routes } basename = { baseUrl } />
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by reverting my boot.tsx file to the original template version, and placing my App component in the routes.tsx file instead.  You can see I just wrapped everything in the new App element.  Here's the new routes.tsx file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';
import { App } from './components/App';

export const routes = <App>
  <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
    <Route path='/counter' component={ Counter } />
    <Route path='/fetchdata' component={ FetchData } />
  </Layout>
</App>;
```

And here's my modified App component that works with this version:

```
export class App extends React.Component<AppProps, {}> {
    constructor(props: AppProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { stateDescription: 'My Cool App State' };
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div className='appContainer'>
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```